# ASP.NET MVC Serve Static Files with routes.RouteExistingFiles = true

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, iis-8

Hi new to MVC and routing.  I am used to the old ways virtual directories, queries strings, ect... ASP.NET Web Forms and Classic ASP is my background mainly.

I am trying to learn MVC and as I am, I always start with organization.  I actually do not like how everything will be chucked into one folder for each model view controller.  I have thought of ways to separate out code for controllers by using partial classes and an initial stub and creating sub-folders.  But didn't really like that idea... as I researched I came across this wonderful example which I liked

http://www.matthewrenze.com/articles/clean-architecture-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

I have it working except on static files  I know at the bottom he mentions something about setting up a class.  And for my eyes I have a tough time believing I have to program the recognition of static files into a class somewhere and wire it up somewhere else for the web server to serve it.

I have tried doing

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.js");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.css");
```

That doesn't get me anywhere.  I even tried a simple rule redirect

```
<rule name="Redirect Css Files" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^Content/*.css" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/Content/Css/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

that caused a infinite loop....

and I tried various other things.  I must be missing something.  Like I said, not to familiar with routing... As I am learning node I found routes a lot easier to understand there then I do in .net.

Help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay well I figured it out.  I typed the example incorrectly

```
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" verb="*.cshtml" path="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
```

should have been this

```
  <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
```

I also found out that as long as the file exists, it should always use it even when routing is not there.  Which makes more sense to me.

have a good one,

Angela